# Plot monthly and annual mean on a single plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot monthly and annual temperature. Based on some examples on this forum I have assembled the monthly annual data. However, aggregation created data which is sorted by month and year. How could I plot this data by beginning with January 1995 in R base plot or ggplot?

```
tt<- rnorm(4018, 5, 8)
date<-seq(as.Date('1995-01-01'),as.Date('2005-12-31'),by = 1)
df<-data.frame(date,tt)
df$Month <- months(df$date)
df$Year <- format(df$date,format="%y")
df1<-aggregate(tt ~ Month + Year , df , mean)
```

Comment: A particularly nice way to visualise this kind of data is using a 'cycle plot'. @Ramnath gives an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826703/how-to-replicate-a-monthly-cycle-chart-in-r

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can do the following:

```
tt<- rnorm(4018, 5, 8)
date<-seq(as.Date('1995-01-01'),as.Date('2005-12-31'),by = 1)
df<-data.frame(date,tt)
df$Month <- months(df$date)
df$Year <- format(df$date,format="%y")
df1<-aggregate(tt ~ Month + Year , df , mean)

#make a date column
df1$date <- as.Date(paste('01', df1$Month, df1$Year), format='%d %B %y')

#plot tt over the dates made above
plot(df1$date, df1$tt)
```

[image]